# Hero Carousel Problems

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider, carousel

The slider/carousel I'm trying to implent is this: http://www.paulwelsh.info/jquery-plugins/hero-carousel/

I know that I have to add HTML code for it, which I am unable to due to little experience with designing websites (started my course around a month ago). Can you help me with the HTML code I am supposed to add to get this to work? This is my HTML, CSS & Javascript. The HTML is what I THINK it should look like, which is obviously wrong.

**HTML**

```
<div class="hero">
<div class="hero-carousel">


<article>
  <img src="images/deadmau5/slide1.jpg" />

</article>

<article>
  <img src="images/deadmau5/slide2.jpg" />

</article>

<article>
  <img src="images/deadmau5/slide3.jpg" />

</article>
<article>

  <img src="images/deadmau5/slide4.jpg" />

</article>

</div>
</div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.hero-carousel').heroCarousel({
            easing: 'easeOutExpo',
            css3pieFix: true
        });
    });
</script>
```

**CSS**

```
.hero {
width: 100%;
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
margin-bottom: 48px;
}

.hero-carousel article {
    width: 980px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 480px;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    }

.hero-carousel-container article {
    float: left;
    }

    .hero-carousel article img{
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        z-index: 1;
        }

    .hero-carousel article .contents {
        position: relative;
        z-index: 2;
        top: 72px;
        left: 48px;
        list-style: none;
        color: #000;
        width: 556px;
        padding: 20px;

        background: rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
        -pie-background: rgba(255,255,255,0.8);

        -moz-border-radius: 20px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
        border-radius: 20px;

        behavior: url(/assets/PIE.htc);
        }

    .hero-carousel-nav {
        width: 980px;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 50%;
        margin-left: -490px;
        z-index: 2;
        }

        .hero-carousel-nav li {
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 48px;
            right: 48px;
            list-style: none;
            }

        .hero-carousel-nav li.prev {
            left: 48px;
            right: auto;
            }

        .hero-carousel-nav li a {
            background: #D21034;
            color: #fff;
            border: none;
            outline: none;
            display: block;
            float: left;
            padding: 5px 20px;

            -moz-border-radius: 20px;
            -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
            border-radius: 20px;
            behavior: url(/assets/PIE.htc);
            }

        .hero-carousel-nav li a:hover { 
            background: #89051C;
            }

        .hero-carousel-nav li a:active,
        .hero-carousel-nav li a:focus { 
            border: none;
            outline: none;
            }
```

**Javascript**

```
jQuery.fn.heroCarousel=function(a){a=jQuery.extend({animationSpeed:1000,navigation:true,easing:"",timeout:5000,pause:true,pauseOnNavHover:true,prevText:"Previous",nextText:"Next",css3pieFix:false,currentClass:"current",onLoad:function(){},onStart:function(){},onComplete:function(){}},a);if(jQuery.browser.msie&&parseFloat(jQuery.browser.version)<7){a.animationSpeed=0}return this.each(function(){var k=jQuery(this),b=k.children();currentItem=1;childWidth=b.width();childHeight=b.height();if(b.length>2){b.each(function(m){if(a.itemClass){jQuery(this).addClass(a.itemClass)}});b.filter(":first").addClass(a.currentClass).before(b.filter(":last"));var d=Math.round(childWidth*k.children().length),l="-"+Math.round(childWidth+Math.round(childWidth/2))+"px";k.addClass("hero-carousel-container").css({position:"relative",overflow:"hidden",left:"50%",top:0,"margin-left":l,height:childHeight,width:d});k.before('<ul class="hero-carousel-nav"><li class="prev"><a href="#">'+a.prevText+'</a></li><li class="next"><a href="#">'+a.nextText+"</a></li></ul>");var e=k.prev(".hero-carousel-nav"),h;if(a.timeout>0){var j=false;if(a.pause){k.hover(function(){j=true},function(){j=false})}if(a.pauseOnNavHover){e.hover(function(){j=true},function(){j=false})}function c(){if(!j){e.find(".next a").trigger("click")}}h=window.setInterval(c,a.timeout)}e.find("a").data("disabled",false).click(function(p){p.preventDefault();var m=jQuery(this),n=m.parent().hasClass("prev"),o=k.children();if(m.data("disabled")===false){a.onStart(k,e,o.eq(currentItem),a);if(n){f(o.filter(":last"),"previous")}else{f(o.filter(":first"),"next")}m.data("disabled",true);setTimeout(function(){m.data("disabled",false)},a.animationSpeed+200);if(a.timeout>0){window.clearInterval(h);h=window.setInterval(c,a.timeout)}}});function f(m,q){var o=parseFloat(k.position().left),n=parseFloat(k.css("margin-left"));if(q==="previous"){m.before(m.clone().addClass("carousel-clone"));k.prepend(m);var p=Math.round(n-childWidth);var r="+="}else{m.after(m.clone().addClass("carousel-clone"));k.append(m);var p=l;var r="-="}if(a.css3pieFix){g(jQuery(".carousel-clone"))}k.css({left:o,width:Math.round(d+childWidth),"margin-left":p}).animate({left:r+childWidth},a.animationSpeed,a.easing,function(){k.css({left:"50%",width:d,"margin-left":n});jQuery(".carousel-clone").remove();i()})}function g(n){var m=n.attr("_pieId");if(m){n.attr("_pieId",m+"_cloned")}n.find("*[_pieId]").each(function(o,p){var q=$(p).attr("_pieId");$(p).attr("_pieId",q+"_cloned")})}function i(){var m=k.children();m.removeClass(a.currentClass).eq(currentItem).addClass(a.currentClass);a.onComplete(k,k.prev(".hero-carousel-nav"),m.eq(currentItem),a)}if(jQuery.browser.msie){e.find("a").attr("hideFocus","true")}a.onLoad(k,e,k.children().eq(currentItem),a)}})};
```

Comment: Try looking at the source of the webpage you linked to

Comment: I have, for very long. All that happens is that the images are centered and displayed vertically, first image first, next below, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the mark-up to:

```
<div class="hero">
  <div class="hero-carousel">
    <article>
      <img src="slide-1.jpg" />
      <div class="contents">text goes here</div>
    </article>
    <article>
      <img src="slide-1.jpg" />
      <div class="contents">text goes here</div>
    </article>
  </div>
</div>
```

Do not forget to add the `jQuery` mark-up like:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.hero-carousel').heroCarousel({
                easing: 'easeOutExpo',
                css3pieFix: true
            });
        });
    </script>
```

This should work for you.

**EDIT** - Try to use `inspect element` or `view source` to help you solve similar issues.

Comment: I was using FireBug and just looking and looking.. I'm trying to do something similar as of http://www.deadmau5.com The slider I'm using is supposed to be acting the same way, that you can see parts of the prev&next image, and that it actually slides. Your code fixed some parts, making it an actual slide. What is not fixed is that, it just changes pictures like that, instead of "sliding" in the new pictures. The images are also not visible on the sides. Any ideas? Edit: Basically doesn't switch pictures at all.

Comment: Managed to fix everything, that the prev&next image appears. The only problem I have right now is that it doesn't scroll through the images at all.

Comment: Can you upload the prototype somewhere, so we can have a look? I guess the `css` might be causing this error.

Comment: Check if you have this script included `<script src="jquery.easing-1.3.js"></script>`. This is my version online - http://bborisov.me/dev/hero/

Comment: Jeez, I'm just.. Yeah, hold on. Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/P2YqR/

Problems so far: 
1. Images do not scroll by themselves.
2. The images aren't "sliding".
3. If you look in the .css file, you'll see I tried to add buttons for next & prev, which failed. 
4. There's also a line in the beginning of the .js file that keeps putting "Prev" & "Next" links in the slide, which I don't want. I just want the arrows to be the ones switching images.
5. I'm not sure what that "easing" part is, and why I have it in my css, if it's even necessary.. (Had webdesign class for like a month, keep it simple!)

Comment: http://www.99lime.com/community/discussion/81/insert-arrows-in-slideshow/p1
If you look at this site. I'd be able to use that code, it's just that, I don't know what to replace the ".slideshow-prev" and those with, since it's different for mine. Can anyone spot what it's supposed to be instead?
Here you can see the next & prev links: http://imgur.com/e0lh9 His left elbow (for him, right for you), the links are sitting on top of eachother, being controlled from the .js, and since I don't that much experience with this, I don't feel like removing too much stuff..

Comment: Latest fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/P2YqR/2/
Edit: So much useless things in the code, or well I think so. That Pie thingy, got no idea what it is..